# Associating a key with a row of QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, model-view, qstandarditemmodel

I wanted to know how I could associate a key with an entry to the QstandardItemModel. This would help me retrieve the row of the entry.

Answer (score 0):

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#details

All the accessor methods to data use:

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qmodelindex.html

`QModelIndex`

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-indexes

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qpersistentmodelindex.html

> The QPersistentModelIndex class is used to locate data in a data model.
>
> A QPersistentModelIndex is a model index that can be stored by an application, and later used to access information in a model. Unlike the QModelIndex class, it is safe to store a QPersistentModelIndex since the model will ensure that references to items will continue to be valid as long as they can be accessed by the model.
>
> It is good practice to check that persistent model indexes are valid before using them.

Hope that helps.